# fixing my current project android - button on click

Tags: android

```
    public void onClick(View v) {  
    int id = v.getId();
         if (id == R.id.button2) {
            counter++;
            changingTextView.setText(""+counter);
            YouLost.setText("");
            final Random rand = new Random();
            int diceRoll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            if (diceRoll == 1) {
                action1();

        }
            else if (diceRoll == 2) {
                action2();
            }
            else if (diceRoll == 3) {
                action3();
            }
            else if (diceRoll == 4) {
                action4();
            }
            else if (diceRoll == 5) {
                action5();
            }
            else if (diceRoll == 6) {
                action6();
            }
            }
        else if (id == R.id.button4 || id == R.id.button6 || id == R.id.button3 || id == R.id.button5 || id == R.id.button1) {
            YouLost.setText("You lost"); 
            counter=0;
            changingTextView.setText(""+counter);  
        }
}
    private void action6() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button2.setX(button2.getX());
    button2.setY(button2.getY());  
}

private void action5() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button2.setX(button1.getX());
    button2.setY(button1.getY());  

    button1.setX(button2.getX());
    button1.setY(button2.getY());
}

private void action4() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    button2.setX(button3.getX());
    button2.setY(button3.getY());  

    button3.setX(button2.getX());
    button3.setY(button2.getY());
}

private void action3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button2.setX(button4.getX());
    button2.setY(button4.getY());  

    button4.setX(button2.getX());
    button4.setY(button2.getY());
}

private void action2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button2.setX(button5.getX());
    button2.setY(button5.getY());  

    button5.setX(button2.getX());
    button5.setY(button2.getY());
}

private void action1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button2.setX(button6.getX());
    button2.setY(button6.getY());

    button6.setX(button2.getX());
    button6.setY(button2.getY());  
} 
}
```

hello :) this is my current long script, I want my app will recognize what button you are pressing on and if its button2 then change button2 place with some other button place (randomly), I did it but sometimes two buttons are set to the same X,Y , sometimes the buttons are dissapear, can someone plz fix it to me? thank you very much :)

Comment: Isn't this Java? This is not a script.

Comment: emm you are right I meant fixing my project, android, ill fix the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your code:

```
   button2.setX(button1.getX());
    button2.setY(button1.getY());  

    button1.setX(button2.getX());
    button1.setY(button2.getY());
```

in above lines you have set x,y of button1 to button2 and now both have same x,y. Therefore, next 2 lines don't change anything.

If you are looking to swap positions of these 2 buttons try this:

```
   float x=button2.getX();
   float y= button2.getY();
   button2.setX(button1.getX());
    button2.setY(button1.getY());  

    button1.setX(x);
    button1.setY(y);
```

Do the above in all action function.